# what is original-title in HTML code

Tags: html

I did much search, but there is nothing explains the meaning and how to use the original-title in HTML code. I even not sure that original-title is Tag or Attribute in HTML and is it the same with title?

I found "original-title" from the source code of this [page](http://www.yellowpages.com.au/qld/coolum-beach/palmer-coolum-resort-14803010-listing.html?context=businessTypeSearch&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au).

Here is the part of the HTML code:

```
<div class="sendToEmail ">
<a id="emailAddressLink" class="emailBusinessLink" href="/onlineSolution_emailBusiness.do?listingId=14803010&classification=MAIN&context=businessTypeSearch&referredBy=www.yellowpages.com.au" rel="nofollow" original-title="info@palmercoolumresort.com.au">
<span class="contact-icon email-contact-icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. It is an invalid attribute and not allowed in HTML.

(Presumably is it is being used by some JavaScript in the page).

Comment: Yep. Also, for people wondering, data-original-title would have been the 'official' way to do this.

Comment: @Quentin Hi, could you do more explain? I do not really understand. sorry

Comment: It has no meaning. It is invalid. Don't follow the example of that page.